# How to Tie a Single localStorage Value Reactively to Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, local-storage

I have a standard React/Redux app, that when loads, initially pulls localStorage values (via useEffect hook that triggers the reducers, etc.), and then stores/saves them when changed.

However, I have legacy code, that stores and saves one of these localStorage values, and saves it directly.

It's all on the same domain so the localStorage value is saved via the React app or legacy code. But I need a way for the React/Redux end to reactively update if localStorage is updated from the legacy code.

Comment: In your useEffect that listen to localStorage, add a function dispatch with the redux logic. Without code, we can't help precisely

Answer (score 0):

You can handle [Window: storage event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/storage_event) like so:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const localStorageListener = (event) => {
     const value = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('sampleValue'))
     dispatch(updateValue(value));
  };

  window.addEventListener('storage', localStorageListener);

  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener('storage', localStorageListener);
  };
}, []);
```

alternatively you could `window.onstorage` property... but IMO listener seems cleaner in React.